# How to parse a range input in java

Tags: java

I want to parse a range of data (e.g. 100-2000) in Java. Is this code correct:

```
    String patternStr = "^(\\\\d+)-(\\\\d+)$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if(matcher.find()){
     // Doing some parser
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Too many backslashes, and you can use `matches()` without anchors (^$).

```
String inputStr = "100-2000";
String patternStr = "(\\d+)-(\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " - " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

As for your question "Is this code correct", all you had to do was wrap the code in a class with a `main` method and run it, and you'd get the answer: **No**.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're double (well, quadruple)-escaping the digits.

It should be: `"^(\\d+)-(\\d+)$"`.

Meaning:

- Start of input: `^`
- Group 1: 1+ digit(s): `(\\d+)`
- Hyphen literal: `-`
- Group 2: 1+ digit(s): `(\\d+)`
- End of input: `$`

**Notes**

The groups are useful for back-references. Here you're using none, so you can ditch the parenthesis around the `\\d+` expressions.

You are parsing the **representation** of a range in this example.

If you want an actual range class, you can use the `[min-max]` idiom, where "min" and "max" are numbers, for instance `[0-9]`.

As mentioned by Andreas, you can use `String.matches` without the `Pattern`-`Matcher` idiom and the `^` and `$`, if you want to match the whole input.

Comment: The question is how to "*parse*", not how to *validate*, so if you "ditch the parenthesis", how are you going to extract the `min` and `max` values of the range? --- The question is about a "range of data (e.g. 100-2000)", so what does that have to do with a regex character class range?